# What is the Acc parameter in roster module mean?

Tags: ejabberd

Many functions in the mod_roster.erl file accept an "Acc" parameter. What does this parameter store? It is always empty in my function calls.

e.g.

```
  get_user_roster(Acc, US) ->
  ....
```

Comment: [Events and Hooks][1]

Acc = same type as the return type of the function

https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Events+and+hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on implementation I would say that is just syntactic sugar over propagating final roster list.

I never used it with Acc =/= []. As I see, non of ejabberd's module does otherwise (always Acc = [], so nothing is appended to roster retrieved from database).

I can imagine that we can call this function with some custom/client data and make implementation of custom module more compact.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to use it for. Passing custom data to the get roster method.